# Sharepoint 2010 MVP Pattern

Tags: sharepoint, mvp

I'm new in sharepoint. Can anyone me with a sample code to use MVP pattern in sharepoint webparts.

Many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Popularity of MVP for SharePoint WebParts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665163/popularity-of-mvp-for-sharepoint-webparts)

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint and MVC/MVP has been asked multiple times on StackOverflow - check out

[Sharepoint to support MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710840/sharepoint-to-support-mvc)

[Popularity of MVP for SharePoint WebParts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665163/popularity-of-mvp-for-sharepoint-webparts)

[SharePoint WebParts MVP Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801592/sharepoint-webparts-mvp-pattern)

Comment: There is no implementation in any of the posts

Comment: Did you actually read them or do you expect to be spoon fed? 1) There is a link to http://sharepointmvc.codeplex.com/ 2) Many people think its not a good idea, SharePoint is built upon webforms, not MVC/MVP so why are you trying to fit a square peg in a round hole.

Comment: Some people may not care about the code quality and having a testable code but I do!!!

Comment: MVP is not the only way to achieve those objectives. Good luck with that square page.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link [Building a Web Part that Implements the MVP Pattern](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7884.sharepoint-2010-building-a-web-part-that-implements-the-mvp-pattern.aspx) has lots of useful links to other blogs.

One of those links talks about SharePoint Service Locator which is worth looking into. More details about this can be read from here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647574.aspx